# Do some cells have more than 2n at some part of their cell cycle?

Tags: genetics

For example, do human cells reach 4n after s phase during interphase after replication of DNA?

Comment: For example megakaryocyte in bone marrow 8n.

Comment: Been told by a colleague that nuclei in early Drosophila embryos don't always manage to keep the rate of division in line with the rate of genomic replication, resulting in some of them temporarily housing 3n or 4n.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytene_chromosome